# Magento2: use Modernizr in my custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, requirejs

I am developing a custom theme in Magento 2.1. I am writing some custom javascript functionalities and I need to use Modernizr. How to I include it in my custom theme?

This is my javascript code:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'matchMedia',
        'modernizr'
    ], function($, mediaCheck, Modernizr) {
        console.debug(Modernizr.touch);
    }
);
```

This script causes a **404 error** since the `modernizr.js` is not found.
How can be added `lib/web/modernizr/modernizr.js` to my custom theme?

Comment: Use Below code  require(['jquery','modernizr'],function($){
jQuery(document).ready(function() { #code here
 });});

Comment: And please add both js file in requirejs-config.js In Magento_Theme Folder

Answer (score 2):

Put the library in your theme:

```
VENDOR/THEME/web/js/modernizr/modernizr.js
```

Then in your requirejs-config.js write something like:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'modernizr':'js/modernizr/modernizr',
    }
}
```

Your javascript code is ok.

Answer (score 2):

This library is already included by Magento, so we do not need to customize anything, just use it:

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'matchMedia',
        'modernizr/modernizr'
    ], function($, mediaCheck) {
        console.debug(Modernizr.touch);
    }
);
```

Tested on Magento CE 2.1.3. I learned from this file, it also require Modernizr as I need.

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/modernizr/modernizr.details.js
```