# Resizing Header Image to display full screen on all devices/screens

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using **Magento 2.1** and am trying with **Modernizr** to get my **header image** fill the **full screen** on all screens and devices.

I have followed the instructions from the link:
*[Magento2: use Modernizr in my custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162149/magento2-use-modernizr-in-my-custom-theme)*

I don't get it working, and since there was no official solution given in the instructions I followed in the link am I hoping someone could help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to set a full height to my header image on all screen resolutions by simply using **CSS**

```
height     : -webkit-fill-available;  
object-fit : fill;  
width      : 100%;
```